# Sending UDP packets to several nodes using ipv6

Tags: sockets, udp, ipv6

Currently, my application code uses udp broadcast to send the packets. While porting the application to ipv6 , how can I send the UDP packets to several nodes. Broadcast ipv4 address cant be passed directly to AF_INET6 sockets.  I am new to this field.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 doesn't have broadcast. Instead, you need to use multicast, and each host wishing to receive the multicast will need to join the multicast group. Choose the multicast group carefully since IPv6 multicast has scopes and flags in the multicast addressing which you need to respect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give some links relating to assigning multicast group address in case of IPV4 and IPV6.

Comment: Can we simply assign some address that comes within the range 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255 in case of ipv4.

Comment: With IPv4 you should use the administratively scoped `239.0.0.0/8` range.

Comment: For IPv6, check out the multicast in RFCs [3956](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3956), [3306](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3306), [4291](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291), and [7371](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7371).

Comment: When I work with IPV4 router, I want to use the same udp broadcast. But the socket creating will be AF_INET6 socket. How can I pass the ipv4 broadcast address to AF_INET6 router

Comment: IPv6 doesn't even have the concept of broadcast. Broadcast interrupts every host on a LAN, and the hosts must then process the broadcast to see if it is for them. Also, broadcasts are limited to the LAN. On the other hand, multicasts will only interrupt the hosts which choose to participate, and multicasts can be routed if that is required. The designers of IPv6 decided a long time ago (20 years or so) to eliminate broadcasts so that there are no more uninvited interruptions.